# Customise table cell using storyboards

Tags: uitableview, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

The table cell should have 3 text lines on the left hand side (lets say title, name, dob) and one text line on the right hand size (score).

Number of rows are generated automatically as well as the content of each cell.

I've tried to create UILabels with Tags inside the prototype cell in storyboard and populate the text of these label, however only the empty cells are displayed with no content.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if(!cell){
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
  titleLabel.text = list.title;
  UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
  nameLabel.text = list.name;
  UILabel *dobLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
  dobLabel.text = list.dob;
  UILabel *scoreLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
  scoreLabel.text = list.score;

  return cell;
}
```

What is wrong with my code/ are there any other solutions?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CellIdentifier must be match cell identifier in storyboard.

Try to add label in UITableViewCell in storyboard and custom file for it. It's better way.

Comment: Right! I didn't set cell identifier in my storyboard. Thank you!